# Listing last 3 items (or all if less than 3) in an ArrayList

Tags: java, iteration

Writing a code to return the last 3 items in a list, if the list has 3 or more elements, otherwise return all list items.

But the code looks really bad.
What is a better way to write the same code?

```
   public void test_arrayListItems() {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("item1");
        arrayList.add("item2");
        arrayList.add("item3");
        arrayList.add("item4");
        arrayList.add("item5");
        arrayList.add("item6");
        arrayList.add("item7");
        arrayList.add("item8");

        String items = "";
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        if (arrayList.size() <= 2) {
            j = arrayList.size() - 1;
        } else if (arrayList.size() > 2) {
            j = arrayList.size() - 1;
            k = arrayList.size() - 3;
        }
        for (int i = k; i <= j; i++) {
            items = items + "- " + arrayList.get(i) + " ";
        }
        logger.info(items);
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a succession of two tasks : first you have the identify the initial index of the loop and iterate over the elements of your list distinguishing between a list having less than 3 elements or plus than 3 elements. For this purpose you can use a ternary operator and implement your loop like the code below:

```
List<String> arrayList; //previously defined in your code
int size = arrayList.size();
int k = size >= 3 ? size - 3 : 0;
for (int i = k; i < size; ++i) {
     //body defined later in my answer            
}
```

The second task is about logging elements of your list separated by the string `" - "`, for this task you can use the class [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) in the body of your loop like the code below:

```
int size = arrayList.size();
int k = size >= 3 ? size - 3 : 0;
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" - ");
for (int i = k; i < size; ++i) {
    sj.add(arrayList.get(i));
}
String items = sj.toString();
logger.info(items);
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Is a best practice to define a variable as type of the interface the instance implement it(see OOP principles)
2. Just a little bit out of scope, you can declare your arrayList inline, like in the example I wrote.
3. Try to use available features of List(in this example) like subList rather than cycle(what if you have thousands of elements?)
4. toString on a list will return a string with those list, you don't have to concatenate them
5. it is a bad practice to concatenate strings in cycles because create new strings every time you add + " "

See an alternative solution below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int wantedSize = 3;
        final List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"));
        final int listSize = arrayList.size();
        final List<String> result = (listSize >= wantedSize) ? arrayList.subList(listSize-wantedSize, listSize): arrayList;
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I wasn't able to up vote because of my low reputation, great points made